# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 when running it to device

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've built a framework using cocoa touch framework in xcode and import this particular framework to this xcode iOS project.

**I don't have any issues running the project on simulator.**

However, I'm hitting these errors when running it on device (iPhone) and when building archive (.ipa file):

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/xxx/yyy.framework/yyy, missing
>   required architecture arm64 in file
>   /Users/xxx/Documents/yyy.framework/yyy (2 slices)
>
> Undefined symbols
>   for architecture arm64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Checkbox", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

What could be the settings differences when running on simulator vs running on device? Is it the build settings?

**Update**

I've already set these in the framework:

1) Valid Architectures to arm64,armv7 and armv7s

2) Header Search Path to $(inherited)

However it's still hitting the same issue :(

[image]
[image]

Comment: The framework lacks a 64-bit slice. You need to rebuild it so that it has one.

Comment: Hi matt, how do I add the 64-bit slice? I've check the "Valid Architectures" and arm64 is already there indeed.

Comment: Omg... found out the root cause. it's quite embarrassing to admit that I should have choose the "Generic device" iOS device instead of iOS simulator when building the framework @.@.... Will leave this comment here, just in case anyone who made the same mistake can refer to it